# One get method for each table field (model)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two models that have a relationship to each other. In one particular method I need to pick a field on the other, I usually create a method to pull just one field, if the field in the future subject to change, I will have to change only the return of function .. here are examples

I currently use the following: (this is just an example, obviously there is much more fields to get)

**User model**

```
function getUsername($user_id){
    $this->id = $user_id;
    return $this->field('my_username_field');
}
```

**Server model**

```
function getUserIdByServerId($server_id){
    $this->id = $server_id;
    return $this->field('my_user_id_field');
}
function getUsernameByServerId($server_id){
    $user_id = $this->getUserIdByServerId($server_id);
    return $this->User->getUsername($user_id);
}
```

This is a lot of code to write, because if I want to get more fields, I would have to write kind of one method for each field.. and if I do otherwise then when the field name change I'll have to re-write his name on all calls.. what is the better way?

Comment: Take a look into http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php. By the way, this I'm not a CakePHP user, there might be framework specific ways.

Comment: There is, but what if I change the field name? I would have to change every call to it, is not easier to set up a method for each field?

Comment: so either way is right? is best to copy and paste or a function for each single field? I will just have fat classes (model) but maintenance is easier

Comment: Seriously, what genius up-voted a comment that encourages very bad practice of copying and pasting code around? To bad I cant down vote comments.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to fetch single fields? Especially if you need more than one? This doesnt make much sense. It is more effective to fetch the whole record (all fields, or select the 3-4 you need) and then deal with the data instead of doing multiple queries to the DB. That is inefficient and repetitive, not very DRY.

CakePHP already features a method for that, [Model::field()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_field).

```
$this->Server->User->field('username', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.server_id' => $serverId
    )
));
```

But like I said, why are you not just doing this?

```
$this->Server->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'User'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.server_id' => $serverId
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to create new methods in the models for this. What you would be doing now, I guess, in your Server Controller, would be something like this:

```
$this->Server->id = $server_id;
$username = $this->Server->getUsernameByServerId($this->Server->id);
```

What I think you can do, though, is just call something like this:

```
$this->Server->id = $server_id;
$username = $this->Server->User->field('username');
```

Or if you have (I think) PHP 5.4 or higher just use:

```
$this->Server->id = $server_id;
$username = $this->Server->read()['User']['username'];
```

(with PHP <5.4 you can just split that last line into two).

I don't think you should have to copy and paste loads of methods in the models for this.

Comment: Ok, but what about the field name change? I should to change it in every call of it, right? but if it is the right thing to do, I will do it.

Comment: Well yeah, just return the value from a different index of the array. Cake already has methods on the models for looking up databases, so you should always just be able to use `read()` or `find()` to get what you want in the Controller, and creating different methods in the models is just overkill for this.